# How to get the recursive difference formula between two columns in excel

Tags: excel, recursion, excel-formula

I am stuck on the recursive calculation on excel. Now I have two columns like below:
[image]

Now I need to calculate two results from these two columns:
1/ In every 4 rows, the left column recursively subtracts the right column from the 4 rows number, which means, xt1-xbar1, xt2-xbar2, xt3-xbar3, xt4-xbar4, xt5-xbar1, xt6-xbar2,...
The left column will be called each row, but every 4 rows after, it will subtract the 1st row back from the left column.

2/ Another calculation I need is to recursively get the product from the difference of the columns from two rows, and it is recursive in 3 rows. This means, (xt2-xbar2)*(xt1-xbar1), (xt3-xbar3)*(xt2-xbar2),(xt4-xbar4)*(xt3-xbar3), (xt5-xbar1)*(xt4-xbar4), (xt6-xbar2)*(xt5-xbar1),...

Could anyone help me work out the formula above?
Thanks.

Comment: In *2/*, what should be in the first and last cells i.e. there is one fewer result than there are rows in `xt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints`**<sup>(MS365 Exclusive)</sup>** as per the tags posted, then one could use one of the followings to accomplish the desired output:*

### [image]

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=TOCOL(
    WRAPCOLS(
        A2:A24,
        ROWS(B2:B5)
    ) - B2:B5,
    2,
    1
)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=D2#*VSTACK(1,DROP(D2#,-1))
```

---

Or, To return the whole output dynamically using one single formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _xt, DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),
     _xbar, DROP(TOCOL(B:B,1),1),
     _sub, TOCOL(WRAPCOLS(_xt,ROWS(_xbar))-_xbar,2,1),
     HSTACK(_sub, _sub*VSTACK(1,DROP(_sub,-1))))
```

---

Comment: I didn't expect your `TOCOL/WRAPCOLS` to be roughly 3 times faster than my `CHOOSEROWS/MOD/SEQUENCE` with 1M rows. Worth remembering.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, I was literally surprised to see how you missed this opportunity to use `TOCOL()` with all its arguments as well as the use of `WRAPCOLS()` , honestly wasn't expecting it from you!

Comment: I was convinced that nothing can beat an `INDEX/SEQUENCE`. Maybe the `MOD` did it. I'm too lazy to check though.

Answer (score 3):

### Different Sized Columns Difference feat. a Running Product

In `C2` (Subtraction):

```
=LET(xt,A2:A15,xbar,B2:B5,
    xt-CHOOSEROWS(xbar,MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(xt))-1,ROWS(xbar))+1))
```

In `D2` (Multiplication):

```
=LET(data,C2#,data*VSTACK(1,DROP(data,-1)))
```

[image]

Excel 2021

```
=LET(xt,A2:A15,xbar,B2:B5,
    xt-INDEX(xbar,MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(xt))-1,ROWS(xbar))+1))
```

```
=LET(data,C2#,
   s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data))-1,
   data*IF(s=0,1,INDEX(data,s)))
```